# Is it possible for a flutter application to use RethinkDB?

Tags: database, flutter, nosql, rethinkdb

I'm planning to build an app that uses a NoSQL database and RethinkDB sounds good, but there's not enough info about how to connect a flutter app to RethinkDB, since many resources and videos favor firebase.

So if it's possible to build a database for my flutter app using RethinkDB, how can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use RethinkDB with a flutter application.

There is a rethinkdb_dart package on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/packages/rethinkdb_dart).

There you can also find a example on how to use the package:

> To include this driver in your own project add the package to your pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
rethinkdb_dart: '^2.3.2+6'
```

> Then import the package into your project:

```
import 'package:rethinkdb_dart/rethinkdb_dart.dart';
```

> Connect to the database:

```
var connection = await r.connect(db: "test", host: "localhost", port: 28015);
```

> Create a table:

```
await r.db('test').tableCreate('tv_shows').run(connection);
```

> Insert some data:

```
await r.table('tv_shows').insert([
  {'name': 'Star Trek TNG', 'episodes': 178},
  {'name': 'Battlestar Galactica', 'episodes': 75}
]).run(connection);
```

> And work with the data:

```
var count = await r.table('tv_shows').count();
print("count: $count");
```

Be aware that you will have to set up the database by yourself. 
How to do so is explained in the [RethinkDB docs](https://rethinkdb.com/docs/install/).

Comment: what about changesfeed?